# PKIX Validation Exception in one Project But None of the Others

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, pkix

Here is the exception when I tried to load gradle project in Intellij

```
 Could not resolve com.netflix.nebula:gradle-lint-plugin:10.4.2.
         > Could not get resource '<<jar that is at the specified path>>'.
            > Could not HEAD '<<jar that is at the specified path>>'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The kicker is that I have three other intellij window projects open that reference these as well as other jars from the remote repo that all work and build and run.  Usually this error would mean my certs are out of date but then all my projects would be failing.  Not just one.  I am confused.

To make this a bit worse, I was using it and made some code edits and like 15 minutes after my last successful build this just started and again just in the one project.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000094584-IDEA-Ultimate-2016-3-4-throwing-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target-when-trying-to-refresh-gradle?page=1#community_comment_115000405564. Looks like an issue with the proxy using self signed certs and the certs not installed into the JVM which makes the connection.

Comment: @CrazyCoder wouldn't this be a problem for all projects?  Only one of my four open projects have an issue.  The rest work fine.  I would think a cert issue would affect all of them.

Comment: If this project uses a different JDK, it could be the project specific issue. It may be also caused by some different repository used in this project which has self-signed certs.

Comment: @CrazyCoder uses the same jdk.  In fact, I only have one version installed to make sure I would not have issues with multiple JDKs.  :)

Comment: You can add `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to the VM Options to see what exactly fails and why.

Comment: @CrazyCoder ok so had to reboot for this setting to take affect.  Now I get "SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" which again is odd because no settings have changed and other projects apparently find it.